# Request a specific HOSTNAME(OPTION 12) from specific ip from DHCP server

Tags: shell, dhcp

Is it possible to request the hostname (OPTION 12) from a specific ip without having to intercept the DHCPREQUEST (and therefore wait for the device to disconnect?)

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Give an example of what you are trying to do. Something to do with the client id?

Comment: Are you asking for a reverse `nslookup`?

Comment: @AdityaK Sorry... i m not speak english and maybe I didn't explain myself well. When a device connects and requests information from the dhcp, another option is present in the DHCPREQUEST option ... HOSTNAME (OPTION 12). So, the only way to intercept the hostname is to listen and wait for these requests to be sent to the server. My question is ... is there a way to discover this hostname (OPTION 12) with a device already connected?
or do we have to wait for the device to disconnect and then reconnect?

Comment: @Panki yeeesss...only that it must derive the hostname sent via dhcp and not via dns ...